# Draw a solid dot and arrow line

Tags: tikz-pgf

Below code works fine,but I still think it can be simplified.

```
\documentclass[border=4pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
\draw (0,0.2) -- (0,-0.2);
\draw[-latex] (0,0) coordinate (M) -- ++(1,0) node [right] {A};
\filldraw[red] (M) circle (2pt); 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Output is:
[image]

Now I use two command to draw it,can we combine it to one command?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use a `Circle` arrow tip from the `arrows.meta` library for the start of the path and `latex`, or `Latex` (as in my example code), or any other desired arrow tip for the end of the path:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[{Circle[red]}-Latex] (0,0) -- (2,0);
\draw[{Circle[red,length=10pt]}-Latex] (0,-1) -- (2,-1);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Of course, you can define a style:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\tikzset{
  arr/.style={{Circle[red,length=4pt]}-Latex,shorten <=-2pt}
}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0.2) -- (0,-0.2);
\draw[arr] (0,0) -- (2,0);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The option `shorten <= -2pt` guarantees that the center of the circle (and not the border) will be at the initial coordinate. The value for shorten id the negative half of the length declared for the `Circle` tip.

Comment: Good, but this solution will draw the circle within the arrow line, my original solution will draw the arrow at exactly (0,0) point,which means it will have half circle delta. if add a reference line \draw (0,0.2) -- (0,-0.2); you will see the difference.

Comment: @lucky1928 Add `shorten <= -2pt` to the style; (in general, the shorten length should be half the declared length for the circle).

Comment: @lucky1928 Please see my updated answer.

Comment: Excellent. it's exactly what I want. many thanks.